# Reading HTML document into R

Tags: r

This page: http://www.navysports.com/sports/m-footbl/stats/2015-2016/teamcume.html differs from most other HTML pages with R because I using readHTMLTable does not allow it to work.  All I get as a response is

```
$'NULL'
```

I am trying to take the Punting data out of the page and then import that into R.  How would I import that text if the readHTMLTable does not work?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source of that page, the tables are not html tables, they maybe were copy pasted ascii tables. They are wrapped in `<pre>` tags though, so:

```
res <- htmlParse("http://www.navysports.com/sports/m-footbl/stats/2015-2016/teamcume.html")
x <- xpathSApply(res, "//pre", xmlValue)
substring(x[[1]], 1, 300)

[1] "\r\n\r\n\r\n                               2015 Navy Football\r\n               Navy Overall Team Statistics (as of Oct 24, 2015)\r\n                                   All games\r\n\r\nTEAM STATISTICS                        NAVY          OPP\r\n--------------------------------------------------------\r\nSCORING......"
```

The read in that string with any of various functions.

Comment: But I can't get the punting data from the character values.  I'm trying things over 10000 and it's giving me quotations marks as the result.

Comment: What does _trying things over 1000_ mean? Can you share the code you tried

Comment: Well doesn't the 1 to 300 go by the character number?

If I want to do characters WAY down the page, won't I need to do:

    substring(x[[1]], 5000, 5300)

All I get are 

    ""

Comment: I just increase the number of characters by a lot

Comment: `substring(x[[1]], 1, 300)` was just to show a brief set of output. just use `x[[1]]` to get the whole thing